# How to pass parameters to existing instance of application

Tags: delphi, parameters, message

I am using Delphi 10.4. I want my FMX app to open only one instance, and so I am using a Mutex. I open a URL from my site in order to open my app with specific parameters, and with these my app opens other apps as needed based on the parameters.

So, if `ParamStr(1)` has a value then I skip the Mutex, make the execution that I want, and then end the app with `Application.Terminate` in order not to have another window open.

Now, instead of that, I want that when the app is opened with parameters, and I have already one instance running, to pass the parameters to the active instance instead of opening a new one.

I am quite new at coding, so I searched for it, but I didn't find anything that can make this work.

Update 1

```
  try
if (MutexErr = ERROR_SUCCESS) and (ParamStr(1) = '') then
 begin
  Application.CreateForm(TfrmMain, frmMain);
  Application.Run;
 end
else if (MutexErr = ERROR_SUCCESS) and (ParamStr(1) <> '') then
 begin
  Inc(CharCount, Length(ParamStr(1)) +1);
  Inc(CharCount);
  Data := StrAlloc(CharCount);
  try
   PData := Data;
   for i := 1 to ParamCount do
    begin
     StrPCopy(PData, ParamStr(i));
     inc(PData, Length(ParamStr(i)) +1);
    end;
   PData^ := #0;
   CopyDataStruct.cbData := CharCount * SizeOf(Char);
   CopyDataStruct.lpData := Data;
   CopyDataStruct.dwData := cCopyDataSecurityToken;

   SendMessage(wHandle, WM_COPYDATA, 0, LPARAM(@CopyDataStruct));
  finally
   StrDispose(Data);
  end;

 end;
  finally
    if Assigned(AppMutex) then
      AppMutex.Free;
  end;
```

Main Form

[Latest approach](https://community.embarcadero.com/article/technical-articles/149-tools/12920-using-wm_copydata)

Sorry but I have changed so many times the code in order to try solutions that now it's a mess

Comment: Use `WM_COPYDATA`.

Comment: Hello and thank you for you respond. As I mentioned I am quite new and still learning. I have tried many ways and one of them was WM_COPYDATA but with no result. Obviously I do something wrong with the code but I cannot locate what

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot locate it either, since I cannot see your code.

Comment: Note that FMX is cross-platform but `WM_COPYDATA` is Windows-specific. Do you want a cross-platform solution? There are MANY different ways to communicate data between multiple processes.

Comment: No, at least for now I will keep it only for windows.